# Why did G-d choose to speak creation into existence

Tags: commentaries, parashat-bereishit, creation

“Great art is the outward expression of an inner life in the artist, and this inner life will result in his personal vision of the world.” - Edward Hopper.

In Menoras Hameor R. Yitzchak Abuhav explains: “Blessed is He Who spoke and the world came to be” - speech was the means by which the Holy One brought the heavens and the earth into being, as is written in [Tehillim 33:9](https://www.sefaria.org/Psalms.33.9?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) “For He said and it came to be”. Our Sages teach (Bereshit Rabbah 44:22): “The word of the Holy One is actual deed (i.e. the actualization of it; making actual or really existent; it’s an act of coming into existence)”.

So when G-d spoke, through His words He brought the universe into being. (What He speaks into existence comes into existence).

But why did G-d choose to speak creation into existence? Why did G-d choose to ‘express Himself’ in this way; use speech as His instrument to create? (Why not create things in the way G-d created Adam).

Comment: What does it mean for G-d to 'speak'?

Comment: I recall seeing somewhere, but I've searched and can't find it, that Hashem used the metaphor of speech to teach us the importance of speech, that speech can create worlds, and C"V the opposite. Perhaps, (my own thought) by the creation of Adam since he received the ability to speak, more than the animals, over there it says he was formed, because in his case the speech that will create worlds will be done by himself.

Answer (score 1):

What the account of Creation in Beresheit does is impress upon us a lesson about Hashem’s sovereign power - his capacity to create instantaneously, without great exertion, with a mere word - so it is likely that He chose to do things this way in order to teach Man about Himself and His attributes. The fact that Adam was ’fashioned’ from the dust of the ground likewise seems to me a way of imparting the lesson that He has special concern for Man, and gives his life special attention.

In short, Hashem was teaching from the very beginning :)

Comment: Rambam said that G-d created everything instantaneously, not six days.

Answer (score 1):

For a person, "words" can exist in "inner space", and they can also exist in "outer space".

*Le'mashal*, for one who learns *torah lishmah*, the words are real and exist in inner-space, hence nothing else is needed. However, for one who learns *torah she'lo lishmah*, the words are extraneous and exist in "outer space" and are not part of the self, hence additional motivation is needed.

An act of creation occurs when one takes words that exist in "inner space" and one projects these into "outer space" and to the real world. This is always the creative process, whether it is of an architect, a painter or a poet.

So Hashem spoke and the world came into being.